# Why does the following hold? $u_{k+1}\le(1+AT/N)u_k+BT^pN^{-p}$ implies $u_k\le e^{AT}u_0+\frac{B}{A}\frac{T^{p-1}}{N^{p-1}}(e^{AT}-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction

I have read a lemma in "Numerical Integration of Stochastic Differential Equations" of G.N.Milstein, which was stated without any proof as follows:

Suppose that for arbitrary natural number $N$ and $k=0,...,N$, we have
$$u_{k+1}\leq (1+Ah)u_k+Bh^p,$$
where $h=T/N,A\geq 0, B\geq 0,p\geq 1,u_k\geq 0,k=0,...,N.$ Then
$$
u_k\leq e^{AT}u_0+\frac{B}{A}(e^{AT}-1)h^{p-1}
$$
(where for $A=0$, we put $(e^{AT}-1)/A $ equal to zero).

The author said that it was a well-known result, and I tried to proof this lemma by induction as well as looked for it on the Internet; however, I failed. Can anyone help me to proof this lemma, or have any website containing the proof? Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure that the RHS has only $u_k$ that depend on $k$ ?

Comment: I think so, I just copy it from the original book.

Comment: Welcome. I've answered, but also I've updated your title - you should include specific titles so that people can know at a glance if they can or want to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}u_{k+1}&\le(1+AT/N)u_k+BT^pN^{-p}\\&\le(1+AT/N)[(1+AT/N)u_{k-1}+BT^pN^{-p}]+BT^pN^{-p}\\&=(1+AT/N)^2u_{k-1}+BT^pN^{-p}(1+1+AT/N)\\&\le(1+AT/N)^2[(1+AT/N)u_{k-2}+BT^pN^{-p}]+BT^pN^{-p}(2+AT/N)\\&=(1+AT/N)^3u_{k-2}+BT^pN^{-p}(1+(1+AT/N)+(1+AT/N)^2)\\&\le\cdots\\&\le(1+AT/N)^{k+1}u_0+BT^pN^{-p}\cdot\sum_{m=0}^{k}(1+AT/N)^m\\&=(1+AT/N)^{k+1}u_0+BT^pN^{-p}\cdot\frac{(1+AT/N)^{k+1}-1}{AT/N}\\&=(1+AT/N)^{k+1}u_0+\frac{B}{A}\frac{T^{p-1}}{N^{p-1}}\cdot((1+AT/N)^{k+1}-1)\end{align}$$

Whenever $k\le N$. Using [the monotonicity of the limit for $e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608441/815585), and swapping $k$ for $k+1$, we get for all $k\le N$: $$\begin{align}u_k&\le(1+AT/N)^Nu_0+\frac{B}{A}h^{p-1}((1+AT/N)^N-1)\\&\le e^{AT}u_0+\frac{B}{A}h^{p-1}(e^{AT}-1)\end{align}$$Holds.

Hope this helps, feel free to query further.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @hungT You’re very welcome